# Do "int i = 10;" and "int i; i=10;" perform different functions when i is a global variable?

Tags: c

Please refer the program shown below. I get the following compiler warnings.

bash-3.2$ gcc -Wall test1.c
test1.c:6: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
test1.c:6: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘j’

Usually this warning is thrown when runtime operation is written outside the function. So I am questioning why in a global scope, "int j; j=20" throws warning but "int i = 10" does not?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int i = 10;

   int j;
   j=20;

   int
   main(void)
   {
       int k;

       k = 30;

       printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Did you read the warning until the end?

Comment: @DeiDei: I see it now. "warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘j’" is  actually telling that j=20 is a declaration. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
j=20;
```

is not an assignment. It is a declaration of `j`, which uses an implicit type of `int`.

C let you make multiple declarations of the same variable in the global scope, as long as they match:

```
int j;
int j;
int j = 20;
```

Pre-C99 C standards also assume the type of `int` when you do not specify any type.

Here is how you can break your example:

```
double j;
j = 20;
```

This does not compile, because `j` is declared as `double` and then re-declared as an `int`.

Comment: Note that implicit int is only valid in C89 and invalid in C99 and later.

Comment: @DeiDei You are right, I should mention that this practice has been prohibited for quite a while.

Comment: The tentative definitions are also legal in C99 and C11. It is only the implicit int that "stopped working" in C99

Answer (score 0):

int i;
Is a tentative definition.
The following definition I=10; convert it to a declaration.